# Multiple values returned when using Elbow method to find the number of clusters

Tags: r, machine-learning, parallel-processing, cluster-analysis

I am try Elbow method to find the number of clusters in my data which was named as "data.clustering". It has to features: age and gender. The head of it as follow:
head(data.clustering);

```
> head(data.clustering)
age gender
2 2 1
3 6 2
4 2 1
5 2 1
6 6 2
7 6 1
```

My code to find k-clusters value on "data.clustering" data frame:

```
# include library
require(stats)
library(GMD)
library(ggplot2)
library(parallel)
# include function
source('~/Workspaces/Projects/RProject/MovielensCluster/readData.R');
###
elbow.k <- function(mydata){
## determine a "good" k using elbow
dist.obj <- dist(mydata);
hclust.obj <- hclust(dist.obj);
css.obj <- css.hclust(dist.obj,hclust.obj);
elbow.obj <- elbow.batch(css.obj);
# print(elbow.obj)
k <- elbow.obj$k
return(k)
}
# include file
filePath <- "dataset/u.user";
data.original <- readtext.tocsv(filePath);
data.convert <- readtext.convert(filePath);
data.clustering <- data.convert[,c(-1,-4)];
# find k value
no_cores <- detectCores();
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores);
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(GMD));
clusterExport(cl, list("data.clustering", "data.original", "elbow.k", "clustering.kmeans"));
start.time <- Sys.time();
k.clusters <- parSapply(cl, c(1:3), function(x) elbow.k(data.clustering));
end.time <- Sys.time();
cat('Time to find k using Elbow method is',(end.time - start.time),'seconds with k value:', k.clusters);
```

As you can see in elbow.k function. I just return k value, but after I ran the snippet code above, the result have three k return as the same value is:

```
Time to find k using Elbow method is 38.39039 seconds with k value: 10 10 10
```

The expectation of my result is:

```
Time to find k using Elbow method is 38.39039 seconds with k value: 10
```

Can anyone help me to fix it ?

Comment: you don't need the `;` in R by the way

Comment: @Vincent Bonhomme Can you explain me more clear - why ? Thanks so much

Comment: you don't need the `;` at the end of your line, in R language. Don't know how to make it clearer ;)

Comment: Yes. Thanks ! But I think, when you don't use ';' in function. It will print value on R console. It not comfortable

Comment: No it won't. Try it.

Comment: You right. I am sorry =D

Comment: Beware that the clustering is biased towards the year. Because you assume that gender = 1 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code work well. But you must edit the line code

```
k.clusters <- parSapply(cl, c(1:3), function(x) elbow.k(data.clustering));
```

to

```
k.clusters <- parSapply(cl, 1, function(x) elbow.k(data.clustering));
```

The second value will make the number of k return match with your expectation. It just simple mistake in your function.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. It just a mistake in a parameter.